# AngularJS DOM nodes leak

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-leaks, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

We have been struggling to resolve memory leaks in AngularJS when routing from one page to the other using ngRoute and uiRoute. It appears to me that there are a lot of people having the same issue but have not come across any resolution which worked for us.

After spending countless hours we have kind of given up and will appreciate any help. We are using AngularJS to build an enterprise application. We use uiRoute to navigate from one page to another. Simple navigating seems to cause memory leaks.

Here is a [plunk](http://embed.plnkr.co/o6VALYIdFryc4sj9FKah/preview) we have created to reproduce the leak.

Thanx in advance for any assistance.